# Undefined reference to vtable for WaypointModel

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake, vtable

So I'm getting this error message in QTcreator, undefined reference to table for waypointModel. This seems to be a common problem, and I've tried the solutions suggested on this site. Everything from running Qmake again, rebuilding, cleaning. Going through my makefile and program.pro file. Every header and source file is separated and on its right place in both the makefile and program.pro file. Yet I still get the error.

My waypointModel class isn't the only class being derived from the model Class, could this be the problem?

I also got the error on my destructor, but this disappeared when I initialised it in the header file as so:

```
     virtual ~WaypointModel(){};
```

Why this suddenly work I don't know, any suggestions as to what may be the problem?

## EDIT:

I want to add that the WaypointModel class is almost a direct copy of another class that was already existing, derived from the same class, but with another name, some extra data variables etc. This class does not experience the problems I'm facing now, even tho my class is almost a direct copy of it.

#Header #   My derived class, and the source of the problem it seems.

```
Class WaypointModel: public Model
{
public:
     // some functions
private: 
  //constructor / destructor 
  WaypointModel(const int unsigned int a_waypointNumber ); 
  virtual ~WaypointModel(); 

  //some data
  unsigned int m_waypointNumber;
  };
```

## Header2 #

A general class, used as a baseclass for all other model classes.

```
class Model: public objectclass // 
{
public:
//some functions
protected:

//construtor / destructor 
Model(const std::string& a_classname);
virtual ~Model();

};
```

## Source file WaypointModel

```
 WaypointModel::WaypointModel(const unsigned int a_waypointNumber ) 
 :Model("Modelname"), m_waypointNumber (a_waypointNumber)
 {
  // somefunc
 }

 WaypointModel::~WaypointModel()
 {
 }
```

Comment: Do you have implementations of all virtual functions in the inheritance tree (including the base classes)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, everything is in order on that front.

Comment: My guess is that WaypointModel.cpp is not compiled or linked. Try making a syntax error in it and see if the compiler will complain.

Comment: Actually, if that is your WaypointModel.cpp, there is a syntax error right now (unterminated `"` in initializer of `Model`) so it is not compiled.

Comment: That mistake is not in the original code, a mistake from my part, ill fix it. But I did as you said, got a syntax-error right away.